# keep filter after ag-grid update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to keep a grid's filter after updating a row.

When I click on a row in the grid, I open a dialog where I update the informations for this row, and then I look for the clicked row in the grid's rowData after that I update the corresponding record in the rowData with the values from the dialog, as following :

```
row[0].x = dg.x;
row[0].y = dg.y;
dg.gridOptions.rowData[index] = row[0];
dg.gridOptions.api.setRowData(newRows);
```

But after this I loose the filter on the grid, I did some search and I tried all the following solutions :

1. Setting the `gridOptions` property `deltaRowDataMode` to `true`.
2. `filterParams: {apply: true, newRowsAction: 'keep'}`

But none of these has worked.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: after grid, apply filter again using getFilterInstance(<column>)

Comment: Show your `updateGrid` function, and any other relevant code. You probably need to do your update differently. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/

Comment: @thirtydot please check my edit.

Comment: Well, you can't use `setRowData` if you want to keep your filter selection, here's a quote from the link in my previous comment: "When you call api.setRowData(newData), the grid _discards all previous selections and **filters**_, and completely overwrites the old data with the new.". Read through the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/) and look at the demos/code to find the solution. If you need more help, let me know and I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 26):

You can set the filterParams newRowsAction to keep, like that

```
dg.defaultColDef = { filterParams: { newRowsAction: 'keep'}} ;
```

refer to https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/index.php

Answer (score 14):

Use this method (`gridOptions.api.refreshCells()`) instead of `setRowData`. Or if you need to use `setRowData`, save the filter model before the call and apply the filter again afterwards using these methods:

```
const model = this.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();
//some code
this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(model);
```

Comment: This option worked, while the newRowsAction didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and this what I did to resolve it (kinda hacky).

1. Subscribe to rowDataChanged event of the ag grid.

```
(rowDataChanged)="onRowDataChanged($event)"
```

2. Inside the `onRowDataChanged` put your filtration logic

```
// Get a reference to the name filter instance
const filterInstance = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance('fieldNameHere');
// Call some methods on Set Filter API that don't apply the filter
filterInstance.setModel({
    type: 'contains', // type of filter
    filter: 'yourData' // set filter on data
});
// Get grid to run filter operation again
this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
```

`onRowDataChanged` will be triggered twice, first when the grid clears everything and second when the data reloaded. So, you should put some conditions to avoid any errors.

For example, I needed to set the filter from the data that was loaded after the refresh this is what I did:

```
const filtered = this.rowData.filter(x => x.Id === this.Id);
if (filtered.length > 0) {
    // Get a reference to the name filter instance
    const filterInstance = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance('fieldNameHere');
    // Call some methods on Set Filter API that don't apply the filter
    filterInstance.setModel({
        type: 'contains', // type of filter
        filter: filtered[0].name // set filter on data
    });
    // Get grid to run filter operation again
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
}
```