# ag grid react - server side pagination - infinate model - filter not working - order of attributes

Tags: reactjs, model, ag-grid

If order of the attributes in json is different, then ag grid is not accepting the response.

Records on grid are on this model for first page `1-100`

```js
[
{
    titlerow: 1,
    name: 'anand',
    salary: 123,
    function: 'tester',
    experience: 0,
    occupation: 'functional',
    
},
{
    titlerow: 1,
    name: 'bachan',
    salary: 123,
    function: 'tester',
    experience: 0,
    occupation: 'functional'
    
}, ......100 records
]
```

when i send request to filter is gone

```js
{"startRow":0,"endRow":100,"sortModel":[],"filterModel":{"name":{"type":"contains","filter":"bac","filterType":"text"}}}
```

response is below:

```js
[
{
    function: 'tester',
    name: 'bachan',
    salary: 123,
    occupation: 'functional',
    experience: 0,
    titlerow: 1
}
]
```

I have observed the behaviour that if order of attributes is different then rest of the records. grid is not displaying the record.

How can i display records irrespective of their order of the attributes in json

Comment: I would guess that the order has nothing to do with it, and that your problem is caused by something else. But there's not enough code in your question to help (and also no demo). What version of ag-grid?

Comment: the version is 20.0.2

Comment: That's quite an old version, from around 2019, it's important to include info like that in future questions. There might be some bug that has been fixed in a future version, I'm not sure. It's not interesting to help with old versions, I might just end up debugging stuff the ag-grid team has already fixed. Best guess, you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533098/keep-filter-after-ag-grid-update